# Why are Nix programs not able to resolve mDNS names when native programs are?

Tags: fedora, avahi, mdns, nixos, nix

My native programs (on Fedora) are able to resolve mDNS / Avahi / zeroconf names, like so:

```
$ ping felonyspork.local -c 1  
PING felonyspork.local (192.168.88.169) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.88.169 (192.168.88.169): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.73 ms

--- felonyspork.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.734/1.734/1.734/0.000 ms

$ ssh felonyspork.local        
Last login: Mon Apr 25 16:05:34 2022 from 192.168.88.200

$ exit
Connection to felonyspork.local closed.
```

However, my Nix-installed programs are not:

```
$ nix-shell -p openssh ssh-tools

[nix-shell:~/src/nixconfig]$ ssh-ping -c 1 felonyspork.local
SSHPING felonyspork.local

--- felonyspork.local ping statistics ---
1 requests transmitted, 0 requests received, 100% request loss

[nix-shell:~/src/nixconfig]$ ssh felonyspork.local
ssh: Could not resolve hostname felonyspork.local: Name or service not known
```

I have mDNS configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:      files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

And `avahi-daemon` is running on my system.

How can I get Nix programs to correctly resolve mDNS names? This is especially important, because deploying with Morph requires a working Nix SSH session.

Answer (score 2):

The missing link here is `nscd`; simply installing `nscd` and starting the daemon makes the Nix-installed programs work.

```
$ sudo dnf install nscd
$ sudo systemctl start nscd.service
$ nix-shell -p ssh-tools

[nix-shell:~]$ ssh-ping felonyspork.local
SSHPING felonyspork.local
Pong from felonyspork.local: ssh_seq=1 time=2191 ms
Pong from felonyspork.local: ssh_seq=2 time=1310 ms
^C
--- felonyspork.local ping statistics ---
2 requests transmitted, 2 requests received, 0% request loss
```